# Route in Laravel doesnt work on get Methode

Tags: php, laravel

I have tried to create a route with GET methode and doesnt work !!!
the route i would like to see on browser bar

```
http://*******:8000/products/categories/index
```

My controller

```
    public function index(Request $request)
{
    $categories = Category::where('parent_id', null)->orderby('name', 'asc')->get();
    return view('products.categories.allcategories', compact('categories'));
}
```

My View folder for catategories under products

```
views
  products
    categories
```

My Route file

```
Route::get('products/categories', [CategoryController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
```

when type php artisan route:list i have my route listed but when i try to get the category page it show 404 not found :

```
http://********:8000/products/categories
```

if i change the route to this and controller index function to list then it works

```
Route::get('products/categories/list', [CategoryController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
```

any idea where i made error !

Comment: Please post the **full** `route:list` output. My suspicion is there's a `products/{product}` route that's conflicting.

Comment: yes i have one route for products as you mentionne `products/{product}`

Comment: That's your problem, then; it thinks `categories` is a product name/ID. See my full answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `products/{product}` route is conflicting with the `products/categories` one; it's trying to find a product matching `categories`.

This can typically be resolved by reordering the two routes in the routes file, or adding a `->where('^[0-9]+$')` constraint to the `products/{product}` route if `{product}` is supposed to be numeric.

Comment: thank you !
now i should edit my route as my route for products is a resource
`Route::get('products/{product}->where('^[0-9]+$')'), ProductController::class);`

Comment: no i have to change it to `Route::get('products/{product}->where('^[0-9]+$')', ProductController::class);` 
correct ?

Comment: You've got a missing `)`, but essentially, yes.

Answer (score 0):

you should try `php artisan route:cache`
i use that code after add new route always and it's work

Comment: I will try and tell you :)

Comment: i tried it and still same problem !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You're going to the wrong url you need to go to

```
localhost:8000/products/categories
```

The index method does not relate to the URL but the action.

Comment: Of course i am typing localhost:8000/products/categories but still same problem